# My discord js bot is not saying anything in the voice channel when it joins

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, bots, discord, discord.js

My discord js bot is not saying anything in the voice channel when it joins. I wanted it to play the test (1).mp3  file. Instead, it just joins and does nothing. If it makes any difference, I'm using repl.it.

Here is the part of the code

```
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + 'voice') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      const connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join().then (connection =>{
        message.channel.send("Joined!")
        connection.playFile('test (1).mp3')
      })
    } else {
        message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }
});
```

and the full file is [here](https://pastebin.com/bMrbbEmT).

Comment: Does it send the `Joined!` message?

Comment: no it doesn't @dan1st

Comment: Maybe remove the `const connection=await`

Comment: You wait for it and register a listener when the bot joined...

Comment: I removed ```const connection=await```, but it didn't change anything, and it still has the same effect as it did before.